# Microsoft WASAPI - Do different audio formats need different data in the buffer, for the same wave

Tags: c++, audio, wasapi

Lets say I want to play a sine wave using WASAPI.

Will the data I enter into the AudioClient buffer always just be samples between -1 and 1, or will it be different between PCM and IEEE_Float Formats, and other formats for that matter.

Thanks.

Right now i'm just using 1 to -1, but i want to know whether or not i need to write my buffer input code different for each format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MEDIASUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/audio-subtypes) / `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` audio types operate with floating point values in [-1, +1] range.

`MEDIASUBTYPE_PCM` / `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` has integer values,

> [8-bit samples are stored as unsigned bytes, ranging from 0 to 255. 16-bit samples are stored as 2's-complement signed integers, ranging from -32768 to 32767.](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422-winter-2014/projects/WaveFormat/)

You will also find good references here: [How to handle asymmetry of WAV data?](https://gist.github.com/endolith/e8597a58bcd11a6462f33fa8eb75c43d).